# Count values above 0 and count how many match a pattern in a row (in R)

Tags: r, dataframe, count, rows

I would like to count how many rows in each column are >0 and how many of those rows (that are >0) start with "mt-".
The result should also be in a data frame.
Here is an example.

df1

```
mt-abc 1  0  2
mt-dca 1  1  2
cla    0  2  0
dla    0  3  0
```

result

```
above0 2  3  2
mt     2  1  2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R you can do :

```
mat <- df[-1] > 0

rbind(above0 = colSums(mat), 
      mt = colSums(startsWith(df$V1, 'mt') & mat))

#       V2 V3 V4
#above0  2  3  2
#mt      2  1  2
```

---

Actual data has numbers in the column and names in rownames for which we can do :

```
mat <- df > 0

rbind(above0 = colSums(mat), 
      mt = colSums(startsWith(rownames(df), 'mt') & mat))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("mt-abc", "mt-dca", "cla", "dla"), V2 = c(1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L), V3 = 0:3, V4 = c(2L, 2L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: I get this erroe: Error in startsWith(df$V1, "mt-") : non-character object(s)

Comment: @giegie Run `df$V1 <- as.character(df$V1)` and try again.

Comment: still not working Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, V1, value = character(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 55353

Comment: could it be because my data frame has columns with names?

Comment: Can you provide your data in reproducible format using `dput`? The same way that I have shared at the end of my post? @giegie

Comment: not sure how to do it. But I think the main problem is that in the input that you created names of rows are in a column V1. In my dataset, they are as rownames.

Comment: What is your dataset called?

Comment: It is a private dataset which I can't provide here

Comment: You don't need to provide an actual dataset. Take first 6 rows `tmp <- head(df)`. Change all the values in `tmp` and then provide `dput(tmp)`.

Comment: structure(list(AAACCCATCAGGAACG = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), AAACGCTCATTCTGTT = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), AAACGCTGTCGTCATA = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), AAAGGTAGTAACATCC = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), AAAGTGAGTACTGTTG = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), AAATGGACAAGTGGAC = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), AAATGGAGTGTGTCGC = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), AACAACCCACCTTCGT = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c("Nde1", "Snhg5", "Ascl2", "Clpx", 
"Chst9", "Gm5831"), class = "data.frame")

Comment: here you can't see any genes that start with mt and unfortunately all the values here are 0. I hope at least you can get an idea of how the dataset look like.

Comment: That is good enough. Thanks. Can you try the updated answer now?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the most elegant approach in the `tidyverse`, but just out of curiosity:

```r
library(tidyverse)
my_df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
               var = c("mt-abc", "mt-dca", "cla", "dla"),
                 x = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L),
                 y = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L),
                 z = c(2L, 2L, 0L, 0L)
)

df_1 <- my_df %>% 
  summarize(across(.cols=x:z, .fn=~sum(.x > 0))) %>% 
  mutate(var="above0")

df_2 <- my_df %>% 
  filter(str_detect(var, "^mt")) %>% 
  summarise(across(.cols=x:z, .fn=~sum(.x > 0))) %>% 
  mutate(var="mt")
bind_rows(df_1, df_2)
#>   x y z    var
#> 1 2 3 2 above0
#> 2 2 1 2     mt
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I had exactly the same idea and was wondering if it would possible to add both in one summarize command. But I got stuck defining the second case, sth. like: `across(.cols=x:z, .fn=~sum(.x > 0 & startsWith(var, "mt")))` Curious, though, if that could work somehow so that we don't need to merge two separate analyses.